# Share Calendar with .ics file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-client

My Outlook doesn't have E-mail calendar option.

The calendar is shared in the form of. ics files. In my personal account, I can directly share my calendar via email, but recently there has been no option to share as. ics in both the desktop client and preview version. Is there any way to share a calendar? Or it could be a powershell script.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unclear: "there has been no option to share as. ics..." 1. Put Outlook client and server in question *body*. 2. Can you not export the .ics, as in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-an-outlook-calendar-to-google-calendar-662fa3bb-0794-4b18-add8-9968b665f4e6?

Comment: Do you mean there is no E-mail Calendar this option?

Comment: Yes. I have update my question. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to share a single Event or a few Events with other people? Then just send them invites. Are you trying to share your entire calendar so that someone else can always see your schedule? Is this a business environment using business accounts, or is this a personal account and Outlook installed on your personal computer?

Answer (score 0):

To share your Outlook calendar as an .ics file, you can follow these steps:

If you’re using Outlook.com:

Go to Settings (gear icon) > View all Outlook settings > Calendar > Shared Calendar. Choose to publish the calendar and then copy the .ics link.

If you’re using the Outlook desktop software with a POP or IMAP account, unfortunately, you won’t be able to share the calendar in this manner.

For Outlook.com, another method mentioned is:

Click Share > My Calendar> Select “Links to event details”. The middle text field will have an ICS URL. Copy that URL, paste it into a browser, and replace the leading “webcals” with “https” to download the .ics file.

If you encounter issues with the options not being selectable or other problems, trying the following may help:

Use the arrow keys on your keyboard to select the calendar.

Log in using a private browser window to select the calendar.

If it works in a private window, you may need to clear your browser’s cache and cookies.